# Wordpress uses url different from defined in rewrite arg of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have defined the following custom post type + taxonomy

```
$productTaxonomyLabels = [
        'name' => __('Product Categories', 'byronposttypes'),
        'singular_name' => __('Product Category', 'byronposttypes'),
    ];
    $productTaxonomyArgs = [
        'labels' => $productTaxonomyLabels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'description' => __('Product category', 'byronposttypes'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => __('collections', 'byronposttypes'),
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'ep_mask' => EP_CATEGORIES
        ],
    ];
    register_taxonomy('collections', 'products', $productTaxonomyArgs);
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('collections', 'products');

    $productLabels = [
    'name' => _x('Products', 'post type plural name', 'byronposttypes'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Product', 'post type singular name', 'byronposttypes'),
    'menu_name' => _x('Collection', 'name in admin menu', 'byronposttypes'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add new', 'product', 'byronposttypes'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add new product', 'byronposttypes'),
    'new_item' => __('New product', 'byronposttypes'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit product', 'byronposttypes'),
    'view_item' => __('View product', 'byronposttypes'),
    'not_found' => __('No products found', 'byronposttypes'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No products found in trash', 'byronposttypes'),
    'all_items' => __('All products', 'byronposttypes'),
    'archives' => __('Product archives', 'byronposttypes'),
    'attributes' => __('Product attributes', 'byronposttypes'),
];

$productSupports = ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'];

$productArgs = [
    'labels' => $productLabels,
    'description' => __('Products', 'byronposttypes'),
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'menu_position' => 57,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-screenoptions',
    'capability_type' => ['product', 'products'],
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => $productSupports,
    'taxonomies' => ['banaan'],
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => 'banaan',
        'with_front' => false,
    ],
    'has_archive' => 'banaan',
];
register_post_type('products', $productArgs);
```

As you can see, I have defined the post type slug to be 'banaan'. The problem is, that the link wordpress generates (for instance, when clicking 'view' in wp-admin, the uri is `collection/$product_name`. I used to have /collection as base of the url, but I changed that to banaan for testing purposes, but it won't change. I have re-saved the permalinks. Am I missing something here?
*Manually navigating to /banaan/$product_name redirects to /collection/$product_name and gives a 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved the issue. I renamed my CPT from products to product

```
$productTaxonomyLabels = [
    'name' => __('Product Categories', 'byronposttypes'),
    'singular_name' => __('Product Category', 'byronposttypes'),
];
$productTaxonomyArgs = [
    'labels' => $productTaxonomyLabels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'description' => __('Product category', 'byronposttypes'),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => __('collections', 'byronposttypes'),
        'with_front' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'ep_mask' => EP_CATEGORIES
    ],
];
register_taxonomy('collections', 'product', $productTaxonomyArgs);
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('collections', 'product');

$productLabels = [
    'name' => _x('Products', 'post type plural name', 'byronposttypes'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Product', 'post type singular name', 'byronposttypes'),
    'menu_name' => _x('Collection', 'name in admin menu', 'byronposttypes'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add new', 'product', 'byronposttypes'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add new product', 'byronposttypes'),
    'new_item' => __('New product', 'byronposttypes'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit product', 'byronposttypes'),
    'view_item' => __('View product', 'byronposttypes'),
    'not_found' => __('No products found', 'byronposttypes'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No products found in trash', 'byronposttypes'),
    'all_items' => __('All products', 'byronposttypes'),
    'archives' => __('Product archives', 'byronposttypes'),
    'attributes' => __('Product attributes', 'byronposttypes'),
];

$productSupports = ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'];

$productArgs = [
    'labels' => $productLabels,
    'description' => __('Products', 'byronposttypes'),
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'menu_position' => 57,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-screenoptions',
    'capability_type' => ['product', 'products'],
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => $productSupports,
    'taxonomies' => ['collections'],
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => __('product', 'byronposttypes'),
        'with_front' => false,
        'ep_mask' => EP_PERMALINK
    ],
    'has_archive' => false,
];
register_post_type('product', $productArgs);
```

I still do not know what was causing the problem, but changing the name of the CPT seems to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your 'rewrite' in the CPT to:

```
'rewrite' => false,
```

save permalinks.
check frontside of site to ensure it worked. (if it doesn't you may have a duplicate code somewhere...)

then set it back to:

```
'rewrite' => (
    'slug' => 'banaan',
    'with_front' => false,
),
```

flush permalinks again.
Smile (hopefully)

Why have you elected to use brackets instead of parentheses?  You might try using the traditional method.

Comment: I am very sorry for my late answer, I did not have the chance to try it out up until now. Setting rewrite to false does make wordpress change the permalink, but setting it back to `'slug' => 'banaan'` makes the base 'collection' again for some reason, so the it does not fix the issue. I opt to use `[]` because this is just the shorthand notation for `array()`. `()` is not a valid syntax.

Comment: When I add a new product, it shows the sample permalink to be /banaan/product-name, but as soon as I save the product, it changes the permalink to /collection/product-name.